# Bounty visibility to post participants

Tags: discussion, bounty, notifications

When a [bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808398/easily-measure-elapsed-time) is offered do the people that already have an answer on the  question get notified? If not, how can I notify them?

Comment: No, they are not notified.

Comment: No.  You can post a comment to their post to "notify" them.  Not so sure there's any point to that, after all they did not answer your question so it is fairly unlikely that they'll suddenly know a better answer.  Best to not do this.

Answer (score 1):

They do not get notified.

I see that the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808398/easily-measure-elapsed-time) you have a bounty on has 15 answers. Leaving a comment on each answer would notify them back to your comment where they could then see that the question has a bounty on it now. However, this would be highly frowned upon and could possibly end in a short suspension for a user that did this.

Another thing you could do is upvote, downvote, and/or edit each of their answers, which will likely bring them back to that question page and see that there is now a bounty on it. But don't do unnecessary edits and always vote responsibly.

Comment: exactly, I mean yes, that's a workaround but has the downsides you mention plus it's a tedious work to do